# df hanging: Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, storage, df

After a Ubuntu 20.04 machine has been running for some time, and I tried to run `df`, it simply just hangs there.

`dmesg` shows tons of the same error message:

```
[118924.226495] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.226928] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.227149] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.227344] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.227500] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.227701] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.227906] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.228065] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.228354] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118924.228517] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.496105] buffer_io_error: 1440 callbacks suppressed
[118929.496110] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.496422] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.496605] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.496780] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.496964] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.497150] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.497296] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.497445] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.497625] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118929.497855] Buffer I/O error on dev sdh1, logical block 754166359, async page read
[118934.783290] buffer_io_error: 1440 callbacks suppressed
```

How should we proceed next?

Can we unmount `/dev/sdh1`, then remount it, in order for us to run `df` properly again? If so, how do we find the mount point for `/dev/sdh1`, so that we can run the command `sudo umount <mountpoint_of_/dev/sdh1>`?

Tried the following commands but they return nothing

- `findmnt -S /dev/sdh`
- `findmnt -S /dev/sdh1`
- `grep /dev/sdh /etc/mtab`
- `grep /dev/sdh1 /etc/mtab`

Comment: This message is stating pretty clearly that you have a single bad block on the storage device. This could be “just a bad block” or it could be a sign that the disk is starting to fail. What file system is being used on `sdh1`?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*` and get a screenshot of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. Resize the window so the screenshot can capture all of the data. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @matigo Think its using NTFS. Output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdh1` includes `TYPE="ntfs"`

Comment: If the partition is NTFS, then you'll need to boot into Windows to try and fix it 

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to know the mount point in order to unmount it, the device name is enough.  Just do `sudo umount /dev/sdh1`.

If you want to identify the mount point, `findmnt /dev/sdh1` should be enough.